# How do the Oracle DB instance and the local listener communicate?

Tags: oracle, windows, listener

It seems [this my other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81582/connection-through-listener-stops-working-after-vpn-client-is-active-on-db-machi) needs some background:

Basically, on Windows, *how* do the Oracle DB instance process and the listener process communicate? Do they use TCP? Is the configuration of this process done via `listener.ora` or via some other setting in the DB? Does the listener service "contact" the DB service or the other way round?

A rough sketch and/or very specific pointers to Oracle documentation would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix:
Oracle is multi-process database. It does not use threads (on the contrary to other databases). Some of the processes are background ones (Oracle internal) the other ones are user sessions processes. They all communicate via IPC (messages, shared ram).

When user opens a TCP connection to listener, the listener process forks and then executes(exec) oracle binary. This new process becomes a new Oracle session process. In this case Oracle protocol is wired - i.e. it uses only a single TCP connection (port 1521).

There is also more complicated way(especially on RAC). Listener instructs Oracle background process(PMON) and this one forks a new Oracle process, listening on a new dynamically allocated port. Listener then sends a "redirect" message to client process. Client then connects (via new TCP) to the session process.
This redirect message can point onto another cluster node(having different IP address)
PS: due this redirect, you should not use NAT and also both client and server should use the same DNS server(or at least server serving the same records).
I think this redirect message contains a hostname, not IP address.

Comment: Sources: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/dist_pro.htm#CNCPT1274 , http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/process.htm .  And note that Oracle 12c has introduced multi-threading. Part of the reason Oracle 11g and prior were multi-process-single-thread was due to limitations of a 32-bit memory model; each 32-bit process can address at theoretical most 4GB of virtual address space. These days with 12c on forward, 64-bit computing is ubiquitous (at least until someday when whatever succeeds 64-bit). Ref http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn10335.htm.